# Mongoose "find" returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

i'm trying to find all blogs that a user has created with his userId.
I have the following mongoose model for the blog

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');


 var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     title:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
content:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
_creator:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
     }
 })

 BlogSchema.statics.findBlogs = function(id){
var Blog = this;

return Blog.find(id).then((blog)=>{
    console.log(blog)
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log('failed')
})



 }

 var Blog = mongoose.model('Blogs', BlogSchema)

 module.exports = {Blog};
```

then in my server.js i have this

```
 app.get('/get/blogs', authenticate, (req, res)=>{
  var userId = req.user._id
   console.log(userId)
   Blog.findBlogs(userId).then((data)=>{
    res.send(data)

    }).catch((e)=>{
    res.sendStatus(404)
  })


 })
```

but it returns an empty array, how should i approach this?

Comment: Your `findBlogs` takes a user id and then treats it as a blog id. Of course, you don't get any matches. Should be `Blog.find({_creator: id})`, or something like that.

Comment: so what do i need to do so that it treats the user id, as the creators id?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
return Blog.find(id).then((blog) => {
```

should probably say

```
return Blog.find({ _creator: id }).then((blogs) => {
```

Comment: @maxpaj: yes, that you didn't :)

Comment: @maxpaj: no worries :) JFYI, if you respond to other users, you should `@mention` them, so that they get notified of your replies

Comment: @SergioTulentsev got it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
blog.find({creatorid:user.id},function(err,data){
//data will be here
})
```